# Has there been any research done on ideal values for loot drop tables?

Tags: mathematics, game-design, algorithm, psychology

I doubt many people want to grind for an item that has a 0.00001% chance to drop from a boss that takes 30 minutes to kill. I'd imagine there are certain factors that play into how rare an item should be. For example

- if an item is part of a set
- if the item comes from a boss vs a regular mob
- how many stats/magical properties an item has

does anyone know of some research that has already been done or some data on this sort of idea. I can't be the first person to think of this.

Comment: This depends on your game design goals. Do you want the item to be available to every player who is willing to invest a minimum of effort? Do you want it to only be available to the most dedicated players? Do you want it to be a meta-game legend everyone heard of but few have ever seen?

Comment: I'm not really asking about what the drop rate for the "rarest" item in the should be, more along the lines what do people generally find most addictive; that you see the rarest item in the game for every 100 "common" items or for every 1000 "common" items. At what point do people lose interest in farming for an item?

Comment: The thing is that different people will lose interest after different amount of game play time.

Comment: "I doubt many people want to grind for an item that has a 0.00001% chance to drop" - Have you ever heard about Lineage 2 C4 loot tables? They were like this. And (arguably) it was one of the top played games of the time. The relevance is all about the *target audience*.